# JButton setIcon nullPointerException

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

My Code:

```
private JButton stopBotting = new JButton();
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "VisualBot/resources/play.png"));
stopBotting.setIcon(img);

add(stopBotting);
```

Full Code:

```
package bot;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GuiBotting extends JFrame{

    private int controlWidth = 300;
    private int controlHeight = 78;
    private JButton startBotting = new JButton();
    private JButton stopBotting = new JButton();
    private JButton pauseBotting = new JButton();

    private GuiBotting(){

        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(controlWidth, controlHeight);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "VisualBot/resources/play.png"));
        stopBotting.setIcon(img);

        eventStartBotting startBottingEvent = new eventStartBotting();
        eventStopBotting stopBottingEvent = new eventStopBotting();
        eventPauseBotting pauseBottingEvent = new eventPauseBotting();

        startBotting.addActionListener(startBottingEvent);
        stopBotting.addActionListener(stopBottingEvent);
        pauseBotting.addActionListener(pauseBottingEvent);

        startBotting.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
        stopBotting.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
        pauseBotting.setBounds(50, 0, 50, 50);

        add(stopBotting);
        add(pauseBotting);

        stopBotting.setVisible(false);
        pauseBotting.setVisible(false);

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEvt) {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();

                VisualBot.stopBotting();

                GuiPreparation.openGui();
            }
        });

    }

    public class eventStartBotting implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent startBottingActionEvenr){
            System.out.println("Starting with botting...");
            VisualBot.startBotting();
            pauseBotting.setVisible(true);
            stopBotting.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public class eventStopBotting implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent stopBottingActionEvent) {

            System.out.println("Stopping with botting...");
            VisualBot.stopBotting();

            dispose(); 

            GuiPreparation.openGui();

        }

    }

    public class eventPauseBotting implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pauseBottingActionEvent){
                System.out.println("Pausing botting...");
                VisualBot.pauseBotting();
                stopBotting.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
                stopBotting.setVisible(false);
                pauseBotting.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public static void openGui(){
        GuiBotting guiBotting = new GuiBotting();

    }

}
```

When I open the gui I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at darkorbit.GuiBotting.<init>(GuiBotting.java:31)
    at darkorbit.GuiBotting.openGui(GuiBotting.java:98)
    at darkorbit.GuiPreparation$eventStartBotting.actionPerformed(GuiPreparation.java:255)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    etc...
```

I just don't understand, even when I set the full path of the image I get the nullPointerException. I found a lot of answers for this and tried all of them but I havent got it to work. I use Eclipse if that matters

Also failed:

```
package bot;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GuiBotting extends JFrame{

    private int controlWidth = 300;
    private int controlHeight = 78;
    private JButton startBotting = new JButton();
    private JButton stopBotting = new JButton();
    private JButton pauseBotting = new JButton();

    private GuiBotting(){

        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(controlWidth, controlHeight);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/VisualBot/resources/play.png"));
        stopBotting.setIcon(img);

        eventStartBotting startBottingEvent = new eventStartBotting();
        eventStopBotting stopBottingEvent = new eventStopBotting();
        eventPauseBotting pauseBottingEvent = new eventPauseBotting();

        startBotting.addActionListener(startBottingEvent);
        stopBotting.addActionListener(stopBottingEvent);
        pauseBotting.addActionListener(pauseBottingEvent);

        startBotting.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
        stopBotting.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
        pauseBotting.setBounds(50, 0, 50, 50);

        add(stopBotting);
        add(pauseBotting);

        stopBotting.setVisible(false);
        pauseBotting.setVisible(false);

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEvt) {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();

                VisualBot.stopBotting();

                GuiPreparation.openGui();
            }
        });

    }

    public class eventStartBotting implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent startBottingActionEvenr){
            System.out.println("Starting with botting...");
            VisualBot.startBotting();
            pauseBotting.setVisible(true);
            stopBotting.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public class eventStopBotting implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent stopBottingActionEvent) {

            System.out.println("Stopping with botting...");
            VisualBot.stopBotting();

            dispose(); 

            GuiPreparation.openGui();

        }

    }

    public class eventPauseBotting implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pauseBottingActionEvent){
                System.out.println("Pausing botting...");
                VisualBot.pauseBotting();
                stopBotting.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
                stopBotting.setVisible(false);
                pauseBotting.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public static void openGui(){
        GuiBotting guiBotting = new GuiBotting();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "VisualBot/resources/play.png"));
```

The `user.dir` is not useful here.

1. It is an actual file path, whereas the `String` used by `getResource(..)` is supposed to be a `String` that represents a path relative to the class-path.
2. It is not suffixed by `/` so it would be necessary to explicitly add it in order to form a valid path.

Try instead with:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
    "/VisualBot/resources/play.png"));
```

Comment: :) +1 beat me, this is probably first time i have seen you to answer a post

Comment: @Sage  Feast your eyes on [3,181 more](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson?tab=answers).  ;)

Comment: You are quite a resourceful guy. I have checked some of them. Will discuss with you and put some +1 on them when i will recheck them in depth ;)

Comment: I added the "/", copyed your code exactly, i still get the error.

Comment: Could you add two things to your question as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20022434/edit)?  1) The output of `jar -tvf the.jar` 2) The current code used.

Comment: What do you mean with the output of jar -tvf the.jar? And with the code you mean all of my program?

Comment: 1) See the [Jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) 2) Yes, put the edited code that failed.

Comment: If the jar command has to be executed from cmd, it doesnt find the command, I added the code that failed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `img` must be null.  Try adding `/` between `user.dir` and "VisualBot"

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "VisualBot/resources/play.png"));
```

produces `NullPointerException`. So probably: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns null as you don't have `user.dir` defined in your runtime configuration OR the property is defined but it points to incorrect directory and is no file with such name.

Comment: *"So probably: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` is null.."*  That would suggest to me that the *JRE has a bug.*

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")`: will return the user directory without a name separator at the end : `my/example/dir`. Instead of directly using `\` or `/`, try adding a separator after it using [File.seperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)  : The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience.